# Cisco 2960X and Jumbo frames on particular ports

Tags: cisco, mtu, jumboframes

I would like to setup several ports to be able handle jumbo frames.
This will be only for my backup nas connected to ESXi host.
I did create vlan 103 where I changed mtu size to 9000.

Problem is when I want to check accpetation of jumbo frames through vmkping. 
I cannot ping any ISCSI initiator or other host in that vlan.

I find out that I can change MTU size globaly through  `system mtu`command.

Problem is that i want to change MTU size only for several ports.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this document](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960x/software/15-2_3_e/consolidated_guide/b_1523e_consolidated_2960x_cg/b_consolidated_152ex_2960-X_cg_chapter_01001.pdf) you can enable jumbos on all interfaces only.